# How does one use yt-dlp to download *only* the comments to a YouTube video, without the actual video?

Tags: command-line, download, youtube, comments

After searching for such a thing for a long time, I've just discovered that yt-dlp, which I already have installed and use daily to download YouTube (and other) videos, supports **fetching the user comments and saving them as a JSON file**.

But, frustratingly, I cannot find any option to *only* do that, and not also download the video at the same time. How is that done? Is it even possible? If not, that's such a shame, since this is an amazing "stand-alone" feature which I often want to do without having to also download the massive video file. It's near-impossible to implement myself because YouTube makes it extremely difficult and convoluted to stop bots/automation.

I've looked at this manual for a long time now: https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp

Comment: If your primary concern is the amount of data, what about downloading the audio and the comments instead?

Answer (score 7):

You can dump a JSON with `--dump-single-json (or simply -J)` or use the `--no-download` parameter.

```
# writes info.json in working dir
yt-dlp --write-comments --no-download "$url"

# dump complete JSON with comments
yt-dlp --write-comments --dump-single-json -o "$file" "$url"
yt-dlp --write-comments --dump-single-json "$url" > "$file"

# Pretty print with JQ (JSON processor, package needs to be installed)
yt-dlp --write-comments --dump-single-json "$url" | jq
yt-dlp --write-comments --dump-single-json "$url" | jq  > "$file"
```

Then, use JQ to query the comments.

```
jq '.comments' "$file" > comments_only.json # file input
jq '.comments' <<<"$json" > comments_only.json # var input
```

or

`some_command | jq '.comments'`

`.comments` is the JQ selector for the JSON property 'comments' here.

The JQ approach becomes somewhat more complicated if you want to integrate those comments that you isolated with JQ into a another JSON file.

Here is an example where I'm doing this with entries to boost you forward in case you chose to go this route.

```
  old_json=$(jq '.' "$json_file")
  entries=$(jq -s '.[0].entries += .[1].entries | .[0].entries | sort_by(.date) | reverse' <<<"$old_json" <<<"$json")
  json=$(jq -s '.[0].entries = .[1] | .[0]' <<<"$old_json" <<<"$entries")
```

Answer (score 1):

`yt-dlp` has an option called `--skip-download` which seems to work for me. Here's the relevant part of the [documentation](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/tree/2022.02.04#verbosity-and-simulation-options):

```
--skip-download    Do not download the video but write all related files (Alias: --no-download)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also looked at the documentation of yt-dlp, and it doesn't seem
to have an option for downloading only the comments. You could suggest
this feature to the developer.

If you're into programming, you could use the
[YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/)
to get the comments yourself.

The article
[Extracting & Pre-processing the YouTube Comments](https://www.analyticssteps.com/blogs/extracting-pre-processing-youtube-comments)
contains detailed explanations as well as Python code to extract
the comments and write them out as a CSV file.
It also contains advice on cleaning out redundant characters such as
emojis and language detection (if you want only English comments).

Comment: I am into programming, but not into Google accounts. In fact, it's impossible for me to register one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using --get-description. It downloads the description of the Video, not the user comments.

It is an option from YouTube-dl and it is still working in yt-dlp.

Comment: So if it does not download the user comments, then how does this answer the question asking for exactly that you claim it doesn't do?